# Is there a reason why it doesn't go to the 'else if' conditional (TOP) and to the 'else' (Bottom)?

Tags: java

I have these two codes, with variations in them. When entering the values 8, 2, 9 for the top code while using the debugger, it shows that it doesn't go to the 'else if' nor the 'else' conditionals and when I use the debugger for the Bottom , it shows that it doesn't go to the 'else' statement. I think I have the braces correct for the top and I think the bottom does not need any braces. Because 8, 2, 9 is neither ascending or descending order, the output should be the println in the else statement ('Eureka'). Instead, the output is blank (no output).

Top:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Measurement {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int first, second, third;

        System.out.println("Enter three values: \n");

        Scanner val = new Scanner(System.in);
        first = val.nextInt();
        second = val.nextInt();
        third = val.nextInt();

        if (first > second) {
            if (second > third) {
                System.out.println("hooray");
            }
        }
        else if(third < second) {
            if (second < first) {
                System.out.println("hooray");
            }
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Eureka");

    }
}
```

Bottom:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Measurement {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int first, second, third;

        System.out.println("Enter three values: \n");

        Scanner val = new Scanner(System.in);
        first = val.nextInt();
        second = val.nextInt();
        third = val.nextInt();

        if (first > second)
            if (second > third)
                System.out.println("hooray");
        else if(third < second)
            if (second < first)
                System.out.println("hooray");
        else
            System.out.println("Eureka");

    }
}
```

Comment: What inputs were given by you to each of the above programs?

Comment: 8, 2 , 9 for both top and bottom.

Comment: Write `if(first > second > third){...} ...` instead and always use braces.

Comment: @paladin That doesnt work, though the advise to always use braces is spot on.

Comment: What exactly do you want your code to do. In the bottom code, using braces will solve your purpose But, what output do you want to achieve in both cases.?

Comment: I believe the output should print the else statement ('Eureka').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The top code will execute the code after the first inner `if`, but there isn't anything there:

```
    if (first > second) {
        if (second > third) {
            System.out.println("hooray");
        }
        // Code here will be run
        // but there is nothing
    }
    else if(third < second) {
        if (second < first) {
            System.out.println("hooray");
        }
    }
    else
        System.out.println("Eureka");
```

`Eureka` will only be printed if `first > second` is false *and* `third < second` is false. If any of the outer `if` or `else if` conditions are true, the `else` will not be executed.

If you actually apply brackets to your second code, you'll see that it is interpreted as:

```
if (first > second) {
    if (second > third) {
        System.out.println("hooray");
    } else if (third < second) {
        if (second < first) {
            System.out.println("hooray");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Eureka");
        }
    }
}
```

Clearly, this is not what you meant.

You seem to want to print hooray if *either* of the following is true, and Eureka otherwise:

- `first > second` *and* `second > third`
- `third > second` *and* `second > first`

```
if ((first > second && second > third) ||
    (third > second && second > first)) {
    System.out.println("hooray");
} else {
    System.out.println("Eureka");
}
```

Doing this with only nested if/else-if/else's (without `&&` and `||`) is also possible, but you'll need to duplicate a lot of the code. You have to handle all the possible cases:

```
if (first > second) {
  if (second > third) {
    System.out.println("hooray");
  } else {
    System.out.println("Eureka");
  }
} else if (first < second) {
  if (second < third) {
    System.out.println("hooray");
  } else {
    System.out.println("Eureka");
  }
} else {
  System.out.println("Eureka");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are saying you are providing 8 2 9 here is the case.

```
if(8>2) then
if (2>9) then
 System.out.println("hooray");
end
end
else if(9<2) then
 if(2<8) then 
System.out.println("hooray");
end 
end
else 
System.out.println("Eureka");
```

Now over here you can see at top level we have 3 statements if, else if and else. How they work is top to bottom. In case of first statement true rest bottom one's will not work. In case of first one is true second one will work based on this statement result either next statement will work or we will go inside this.

I believe you else should be a part of second level if statement.