# Are there ways to resolve the problems mentioned in the description in order to run the code on Intellij IDEA?

Tags: java

It says, "Class 'Practice' is never used" and "Method 'maxAreaOfIsland(int[][])' is never used" with the addition of "Typo: In word 'trav'".  The output should be the number 6, but it never gets to it because of the above problems. I am trying to fix the problem in order to generate an output.The code was borrowed from leetcode.com. It works in that website's java compiler, but not int Intellij IDEA.

```
class Practice {
private int n, m;
public int maxAreaOfIsland(int[][] grid) {
    int ans = 0;
    n = grid.length;
    m = grid[0].length;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            if (grid[i][j] > 0) ans = Math.max(ans, trav(i, j, grid));
    return ans;
}
private int trav(int i, int j, int[][] grid) {
    if (i < 0 || j < 0 || i >= n || j >= m || grid[i][j] < 1) return 0;
    grid[i][j] = 0;
    return 1 + trav(i-1, j, grid) + trav(i, j-1, grid) + trav(i+1, j, grid) + trav(i, j+1, grid);
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    int value;
    Practice example = new Practice();
    int[][] yourGrid = {{0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0},{0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0},{0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0}};
    value = example.maxAreaOfIsland(yourGrid);
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

}

Comment: How is your class `Practice` being run? How are you running it? Can you describe? And where is `main` method located?

Comment: Exactly. There is no main. I am also wanting to know how is it that it runs on leetcode.com java compiler but not on Intellij IDEA.

Comment: Have you run any other Java code before this? It seems like you are a beginer.

Comment: You should have another main class in your project with a main method `public static void main(String[] args) {...}`, you need to create an instance of the Practice class in that main method `Practice example = new Practice();` then call your method using the instance `example.maxAreaOfIsland(yourGrid);`, otherwise you can make Practise a public class `public class Practice` and call the method directly `Practice.maxAreaOfIsland(grid);`

Comment: @sorifiend is correct. I was going through your profile and I saw you have already asked a question on Java and accepted the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67767966/is-there-a-reason-why-it-doesnt-go-to-the-else-if-conditional-top-and-to-th 

Take a look at your own question, there is a `main` method and THAT is an entry point for any program in Java. I hope it helps you understand the issue. If you are still confused, let me know in comments.

Comment: I have used your comments and have updated the coding. However, the grid I am using for 'yourGrid' isn't allowed.

Comment: The way you are passing arrays is wrong.. 
`int[][] yourGrid = {{0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0},{0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0},{0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0}};
    example.maxAreaOfIsland(yourGrid);` Try this. And also I would suggest learn some more basics of java syntax and language details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the updates/and comments:

The working example is here:

```
class Practice {
    private int n, m;
    public int maxAreaOfIsland(int[][] grid) {
        int ans = 0;
        n = grid.length;
        m = grid[0].length;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
                if (grid[i][j] > 0) ans = Math.max(ans, trav(i, j, grid));
        return ans;
    }
    private int trav(int i, int j, int[][] grid) {
        if (i < 0 || j < 0 || i >= n || j >= m || grid[i][j] < 1) return 0;
        grid[i][j] = 0;
        return 1 + trav(i-1, j, grid) + trav(i, j-1, grid) + trav(i+1, j, grid) + trav(i, j+1, grid);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Practice example = new Practice();
        int[][] yourGrid = {{0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0},{0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0},{0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0}};
        example.maxAreaOfIsland(yourGrid);
    }
}
```

(Note: Explanations are already mentioned in the comments/updates)